# Hbase filters on multiple colummnFamily and qualifierRange returns 0 rows

Tags: hbase

Filter list on single columnFamily works but on multiple columnFamily returns 0 rows. 
Problem statement is same as [How to apply several QualifierFilter to a row in HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379350/how-to-apply-several-qualifierfilter-to-a-row-in-hbase)

but i can not use SingleColumnValueFilter as column qualifier is a timestamp. so my filter looks like :

```
    val master_filter_list = new FilterList()

    val outer_fl_A = new FilterList()
    val cf_filter = new FamilyFilter (CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator("ac".getBytes))
    val qualifier_range = new ColumnRangeFilter(Bytes.toBytes(fromDate.getMillis), true, Bytes.toBytes(toDate.getMillis), true)
    val ac_fl = new ValueFilter(comparison_operator, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes(value.toString.toInt)))
    outer_fl_A.addFilter(cf_filter)
    outer_fl_A.addFilter(qualifier_range)
    outer_fl_A.addFilter(ac_fl)
master_filter_list.addFilter(outer_fl_A)

    val outer_fl_B = new FilterList()
    val cf_filter = new FamilyFilter (CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator("t".getBytes))
    val qualifier_range = new ColumnRangeFilter(Bytes.toBytes(fromDate.getMillis), true, Bytes.toBytes(toDate.getMillis), true)
    val ts_fl = new ValueFilter(comparison_operator, new BinaryComparator(value.toString.getBytes))
    outer_fl_B.addFilter(cf_filter)
    outer_fl_B.addFilter(qualifier_range)
    outer_fl_B.addFilter(ts_fl)
    master_filter_list.addFilter(outer_fl_B)
```

What would be the right way to get only the rows from the table which do have outer_fl_A AND outer_fl_B ?

Answer (score 1):

If outer_fl_A , outer_fl_B is different column families, or same, if you want values eligible for one of your filters, you should use OR to add filters to scan.

Comment: yes, outer_fl_A and outer_fl_B are different column families. and i want values eligible where A and B both are true.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard thing to implement with HBase. The root of your problem is that compound filter(list) predicates are evaluated at the KV level, not on a ROW level.

So a query like

> give me all rows that have (values in) ColFam1 AND (values in) ColFam2 and also return
>   ColFam3 in the results

is impossible to solve with the standard filtersets provided in the HBase distribution.
Remember FilterLists do a MUST_PASS_ALL evaluation by default so when the scanner gets to evaluate a KV like `ColFam1:qualifX somevalue` it will ask the question 'is the CF equal to 'ColFam1' AND equal to 'ColFam2'? Which off course is never true. 
When you switch to MUST_PASS_ONE your results will unintendedly also include rows that have ColFam1 but NOT ColFam2 or vice versa or both.

So don't think SQL-like/row-based where you can say:

> the row must have col1=A AND col2=B

HBase ColumnRangeFilter and (Mulitple)ColumnPrefixFilter can help you out in some use cases but they all work on the qualifier level only

Comment: thanks for explaining the underlying algorithm in hbase, i have implement this with another approach and it's working fine. Can you please tell me if there is any max limit of filters to be added in filterlist. beacuase when i am adding 7 filters in a filterlist it shows, FilterList OR (5/7), and it is considering only 5 values.

Comment: @Manjeet, there is no limit to the number of filter you can stack but I found Hbase (0.94 in my case) to be very picky about the order of multiple filters in a FilterList. I had to put them in the 'right' order in order to get to the desired resultset. But the logic of what was 'right' evades me, but obviously there is some hierarchy in the application of multiple filters to a KV and/or row